# Facebook registration in my app suddenly stop working

Tags: facebook, debugging, oauth, facebook-login

I have a web app with Facebook login which was working fine. But suddenly new users had troubles to use FB to register. Facebook users with previous registration works fine. I am not sure if API was deprecated (in my developers FB page my app it is using API V2.12). Anyway my problem is to debug social registration. Create Facebook account becomes tricky being you need now a phone number each time and it should be a real one. So I was trying to figure out how to create fake users and founded it is possible on FB because you can create test users.
The problem is, when I try to register in my app using those accounts, they fail with the message:

User is not allowed to see the application.: The user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration.

I know this is a standard message when you are trying to use a test user in another app. But I wasn't asked about in which app the test users should be used.
In resume; please enlighten me about the best way to test & debug Facebook users registration in an app.

Comment: is your app live, in the app settings?

Comment: Hi Luschn, yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Recently FB remove 'context' field from User. Being I was asking for that field, Spring Social start to throw a 500 error:

```
String[] fieldsToMap = { "id", "email", "context", "first_name", "last_name", "name", "name_format"};
User user = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fieldsToMap);
```

That was the error, so it was fixed just removing 'context' from the array. Any case I can't understand why Facebook wasn't sending an email to all FB developers warning about the change. 
By other side, I still not having a good way to test FB login automatically. Test users are unable to login into a published app. So, if somebody has a method, please share it.